# wierd behaviour of svg text in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, webkit

I am scaling an svg group on mousewheel using a transform. The group contains a rect and a text node. In firefox and IE this works as expected: the rect and the text are scaled and the text stays in the same position. But in chrome/ipad the text changes differently from the rect : when zooming the text flows in and out of the rect like in these captures:
[image]
[image]

**Update:**
Thanks to Robert Longson answer I discovered [the bug in question](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60317).
You can find more info about text-rendering [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some UAs apply different font effects such as hinting and kerning only when the font is above a certain size so fonts don't keep a consistent scaling when they zoom.

[Setting the attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#TextRenderingProperty) `text-rendering="geometricPrecision"` may help, although there's no absolute guarantee.

If that fails you'll just have to recalculate the bounding box whenever there's an [SVGZoom](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/script.html#InterfaceSVGZoomEvent) event.

Comment: Apparently text-rendering="geometricPrecision" did the trick. Thanks!! I'll re test it tomorrow and accept the answer. Do you have any article or blog post about this?

Comment: @madmed: Based on implementation experience, it's typically more expensive to render glyph outlines (aka geometricPrecision) than picking a given font-size, rasterizing the glyphs at that size and then blitting them (I'd imagine that in some cases this is simply handed off to the OS's text rendering engine). In any case, implementations are likely to prioritize performance over quality if the difference is significant.

Comment: I tried setting body{text-rendering: geometricPrecision;} while it worked on desktop, the performance in iPad was horrible, I switched it to svg text{text-rendering: geometricPrecision;} and it works better now.